# Why WaitForControlExist method waits longer then specified in timeout?

Tags: c#, ui-automation

The following code should check uIBeautyListItem for 50 milliseconds and move on. But the `WaitForControlExist` method waits for 20 seconds. I have tried different values and no luck.

Why does the time-out in my code doesn't work.

```
Int32 int32sec = 50; 
if (uIBeautyListItem.WaitForControlExist(int32sec)) 
{ 
    Mouse.Click(uIBeautyListItem);
}
```

Method signature from MSDN:

```
public bool WaitForControlExist(
int millisecondsTimeout
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken directly from the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee823124%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation:

> When the wait operation causes an implicit search for the control or, when the application is busy, the actual wait time could be more than the time-out specified.

I suppose, that in your case this *operation causes an implicit search for the control*, and that's why it takes so much time.
You might want to change the default [search timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.playbacksettings.searchtimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Playback.PlaybackSettings.SearchTimeout = someValue;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did what you just suggested, playbackSettings.SearchTimeout = 2000;   The fact is that the WaitforControlExists still takes about 5 sec or more to move on. IT is a a little strange. But I can live with it.